# Run jar on IBM i (as400 / iSeries)

Tags: java, jar, console, ibm-midrange

I'm working with IBM i (often called an AS/400 server).

Currently I have been able to create `.CLASS` files and run perfectly

in as400 Directory (I think it's called IFS or something like) a have my tree like:

```
/
+--Javacfd/
   +--bin/
      +--com/
         +---company/
             Class1.class
             Class2.class    
             Hello.class
             Server.class
             +---other/
                 Other.class
                 Another.class
                 Etc.class
```

When I run `RUNJVA CLASS('com.company.Hello')` Works well! Or 
`RUNJVA CLASS('com.company.other.Other')`

Now I need run a executable jar

In windows `java -jar my-jar.jar` Works well

I as400 I tried

```
RUNJVA CLASS('hello.Application') CLASSPATH(':\Javacfd\bin\my-jar.jar')
```

I get

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hello.Application

```
RUNJVA CLASS('hello.Application') CLASSPATH('Javacfd\bin\my-jar.jar')
```

I get

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hello.Application

```
RUNJVA CLASS('hello.Application') CLASSPATH('\Javacfd\bin\my-jar.jar')
```

I get

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hello.Application

```
RUNJVA CLASS('hello.Application')
```

I get

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hello.Application

**Note** `hello` is package and `Application` is a Main class. Jar file is locale in `\Javacfd\bin\my-jar.jar`

I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the jar contains a proper manifest you specify the jar file on the [RUNJVA](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/cl/runjva.htm?lang=en) command [CLASS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/cl/runjva.htm?lang=en-us#RUNJVA.CLASS) parameter:

```
RUNJVA CLASS('/Javacfd/bin/my-jar.jar')
```

You can also use the [standard java tools and utilities](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaha/rzahatoolsstandard.htm?lang=en) through the [Qshell](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzahz/rzahzintro.htm?lang=en) interpreter:

```
QSH CMD('java -jar /Javacfd/bin/my-jar.jar')
```